# MooTools: changing element text, leaving nested elements intact

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I'm confused about the possibilities of setting the `text` attribute, and the difference with setting `html`. Basically, I have a paragraph with an image in it:

`<p id="test">Title <img src="/someimage.jpg" /></p>`

What I want to do, is change 'Title' to something else. So what I do (using MooTools):

`$('test').set('text', 'Different title');`

However, this just replaces the entire contents of the paragraph element, stripping the image element, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4vhtR/1/

I would've expected this to just change the text, the actual text, and not any HTML elements that are contained. Now it just seems the same as using `set('html', 'Different title')`.

Why does it work this way? And how can I only really change the text, without resorting to wrapping the text in a `<span>` or cloning and putting back the image with JS, which would just complicate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do things is via text nodes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue

```
Element.implement({
    getTextNodes: function(){
        return Array.filter(this.childNodes, function(el){
            return el.nodeType == 3;
        });
    }
});

var textNodes = $('test').getTextNodes();

textNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Hi there';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/4vhtR/4/

this will return a collection of all textNodes you can update the value of so you can reference any bit of text you like.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So, there's a bit more to 'text'. Would it perhaps be a good idea to include `getTextNodes` in MooTools, for easy usage?

Comment: it's uncommon to really work on such low level and people get around it by modding the markup and wrapping bits in superfluous elements. mootools-core is at a feature-freeze anyway whilst 2.0 (aka prime) is being written.

Comment: Perhaps this will make it sometime. For now, there doesn't seem much difference between `text` and `html`. This answer is quite helpful when looking for that 'lower level' though.